# Combining datapoints using an index dataframe in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have two dataframes, and I'd like to use one as reference for combining observations in the other one.

First, I have data:

```
> data
           upc fips_state_code mymonth     price units year     sales
1   1153801013               2       3  25.84620   235 2008 6073.8563
2   1153801013               1       2  28.61981   108 2009 3090.9396
3   1153801013               2       2  27.99000     7 2009  195.9300
4   1153801013               1       1  27.99000     4 2009  111.9600
5   1153801013               1       3  27.99000     7 2008  195.9300
6  72105922753               1       3  27.10816   163 2008 4418.6306
7  72105922765               2       2  24.79000     3 2010   74.3700
8  72105922765               2       2  25.99000     1 2009   25.9900
9  72105922765               1       2  23.58091    13 2009  306.5518
10  1071917100               2       2 300.07000     1 2009  300.0700
11  1071917100               1       3 307.07000     2 2008  614.1400
12  1071917100               2       3 269.99000     1 2010  269.9900
13  1461503541               2       2   0.65200     8 2008    5.2160
14  1461503541               2       2  13.99000    11 2010  153.8900
15  1461503541               1       1   0.87000     1 2008    0.8700
16    11111111               1       1   3.00000     2 2008    6.0000
17    11111112               1       1   6.00000     5 2008   30.0000
```

Then, I have z, which is the reference:

```
> z
             upc  code
3     1153801013 52161
1932 72105922753 52161
1934 72105922765 52161
2027 81153801013 52161
2033 81153801041 52161
2     1071917100 50174
1256  8723610700 50174
```

I want to combine datapoints in data whose upc is the same in z.

In the sample I gave to you, there are 7 different UPC's.

1071917100 is also in z, with the code 50174. However, the only other upc with this code is 8723610700, which is not in data. Therefore, it remains unchanged.

1461503541, 11111111, and 11111112 are not in z at all, so therefore they also remains unchanged.

1153801013, 72105922753, and 72105922765 all share the same code in z, 52161. Therefore, I want to combine all the observations with these upc's.

I want to do this in a really specific way:

1. First, I want to choose the UPC with the greatest amount of sales across the data. 1153801013 has 9668.616 in sales (simply the sum of all sales with that upc). 72105922753 has 4418.631 in sales. 72105922765 has 406.9118 in sales. Therefore, I choose 1153801013 as the upc for all of them.
2. Now having chosen this upc, I want to change 72105922753 and 72105922765 to 1153801013 in data.

Now we have a dataset that looks like this:

```
> data1
          upc fips_state_code mymonth     price units year     sales
1  1153801013               2       3  25.84620   235 2008 6073.8563
2  1153801013               1       2  28.61981   108 2009 3090.9396
3  1153801013               2       2  27.99000     7 2009  195.9300
4  1153801013               1       1  27.99000     4 2009  111.9600
5  1153801013               1       3  27.99000     7 2008  195.9300
6  1153801013               1       3  27.10816   163 2008 4418.6306
7  1153801013               2       2  24.79000     3 2010   74.3700
8  1153801013               2       2  25.99000     1 2009   25.9900
9  1153801013               1       2  23.58091    13 2009  306.5518
10 1071917100               2       2 300.07000     1 2009  300.0700
11 1071917100               1       3 307.07000     2 2008  614.1400
12 1071917100               2       3 269.99000     1 2010  269.9900
13 1461503541               2       2   0.65200     8 2008    5.2160
14 1461503541               2       2  13.99000    11 2010  153.8900
15 1461503541               1       1   0.87000     1 2008    0.8700
16   11111111               1       1   3.00000     2 2008    6.0000
17   11111112               1       1   6.00000     5 2008   30.0000
```

3. Finally, I want to combine all the datapoints with the same year, mymonth, and fips_state_code. The way this will happen is by adding up the sales and unit numbers of datapoints with the same upc, fips_state_code, mymonth, and year, and then recalculating the weighted price. (I.e., price = total Sales / total Units.)

And so, the final data set should look like this:

```
> data2
          upc fips_state_code mymonth     price units year    sales
1  1153801013               2       3  25.84620   235 2008 6073.856
2  1153801013               1       2  28.07844   121 2009 3397.491
3  1153801013               2       2  27.74000     8 2009  221.920
4  1153801013               1       1  27.99000     4 2009  111.960
5  1153801013               1       3  27.14448   170 2008 4614.561
6  1153801013               2       2  24.79000     3 2010   74.370
7  1071917100               2       2 300.07000     1 2009  300.070
8  1071917100               1       3 307.07000     2 2008  614.140
9  1071917100               2       3 269.99000     1 2010  269.990
10 1461503541               2       2   0.65200     8 2008    5.216
11 1461503541               2       2  13.99000    11 2010  153.890
12 1461503541               1       1   0.87000     1 2008    0.870
13   11111111               1       1   3.00000     2 2008    6.000
14   11111112               1       1   6.00000     5 2008   30.000
```

I did try to do this myself, but it seems like it could be done more efficiently than my code using dplyr, and I couldn't accomplish the last part successfully. Please let me know if anything is unclear, and thank you very much in advance.

Here is the dput code:

```
data<-structure(list(upc = c(1153801013, 1153801013, 1153801013, 1153801013, 
1153801013, 72105922753, 72105922765, 72105922765, 72105922765, 
1071917100, 1071917100, 1071917100, 1461503541, 1461503541, 1461503541, 
11111111, 11111112), fips_state_code = c(2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1), mymonth = c(3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1), price = c(25.8461971831, 28.6198113208, 
27.99, 27.99, 27.99, 27.1081632653, 24.79, 25.99, 23.5809090909, 
300.07, 307.07, 269.99, 0.652, 13.99, 0.87, 3, 6), units = c(235, 
108, 7, 4, 7, 163, 3, 1, 13, 1, 2, 1, 8, 11, 1, 2, 5), year = c(2008, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2008, 2008, 2010, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2008, 2010, 
2008, 2010, 2008, 2008, 2008), sales = c(6073.8563380285, 3090.9396226464, 
195.93, 111.96, 195.93, 4418.6306122439, 74.37, 25.99, 306.5518181817, 
300.07, 614.14, 269.99, 5.216, 153.89, 0.87, 6, 30)), .Names = c("upc", 
"fips_state_code", "mymonth", "price", "units", "year", "sales"
), row.names = c(NA, 17L), class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"))

z<-structure(list(upc = c(1153801013, 72105922753, 72105922765, 
81153801013, 81153801041, 1071917100, 8723610700), code = c(52161L, 
52161L, 52161L, 52161L, 52161L, 50174L, 50174L)), .Names = c("upc", 
"code"), row.names = c(3L, 1932L, 1934L, 2027L, 2033L, 2L, 1256L
), class = "data.frame")

data1<-structure(list(upc = c(1153801013, 1153801013, 1153801013, 1153801013, 
1153801013, 1153801013, 1153801013, 1153801013, 1153801013, 1071917100, 
1071917100, 1071917100, 1461503541, 1461503541, 1461503541, 11111111, 
11111112), fips_state_code = c(2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1), mymonth = c(3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1), price = c(25.8461971831, 28.6198113208, 
27.99, 27.99, 27.99, 27.1081632653, 24.79, 25.99, 23.5809090909, 
300.07, 307.07, 269.99, 0.652, 13.99, 0.87, 3, 6), units = c(235, 
108, 7, 4, 7, 163, 3, 1, 13, 1, 2, 1, 8, 11, 1, 2, 5), year = c(2008, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2008, 2008, 2010, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2008, 2010, 
2008, 2010, 2008, 2008, 2008), sales = c(6073.8563380285, 3090.9396226464, 
195.93, 111.96, 195.93, 4418.6306122439, 74.37, 25.99, 306.5518181817, 
300.07, 614.14, 269.99, 5.216, 153.89, 0.87, 6, 30)), .Names = c("upc", 
"fips_state_code", "mymonth", "price", "units", "year", "sales"
), row.names = c(NA, 17L), class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"))

data2<-structure(list(upc = c(1153801013, 1153801013, 1153801013, 1153801013, 
1153801013, 1153801013, 1071917100, 1071917100, 1071917100, 1461503541, 
1461503541, 1461503541, 11111111, 11111112), fips_state_code = c(2, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1), mymonth = c(3, 2, 2, 
1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1), price = c(25.8461971831, 28.07844, 
27.74, 27.99, 27.14448, 24.79, 300.07, 307.07, 269.99, 0.652, 
13.99, 0.87, 3, 6), units = c(235, 121, 8, 4, 170, 3, 1, 2, 1, 
8, 11, 1, 2, 5), year = c(2008, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2008, 2010, 
2009, 2008, 2010, 2008, 2010, 2008, 2008, 2008), sales = c(6073.8563380285, 
3397.491, 221.92, 111.96, 4614.561, 74.37, 300.07, 614.14, 269.99, 
5.216, 153.89, 0.87, 6, 30)), .Names = c("upc", "fips_state_code", 
"mymonth", "price", "units", "year", "sales"), row.names = c(NA, 
14L), class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"))
```

This is what I have attempted so far:

```
w <- z[match(unique(z$code), z$code),]
w <- plyr::rename(w,c("upc"="upc1"))
data <- merge(x=data,y=z,by="upc",all.x=T,all.y=F)
data <- merge(x=data,y=w,by="code",all.x=T,all.y=F)
data <- within(data, upc2 <- ifelse(!is.na(upc1),upc1,upc))
data$upc <- data$upc2
data$upc1 <- data$upc2 <- data$code <- NULL
data <- data[complete.cases(data),]
attach(data)
data <- aggregate(data,by=list(upc,fips_state_code,year,mymonth),FUN=sum)
data$price <- data$sales / data$units
detach(data)
data$Group.1 <- data$Group.2 <- data$Group.3 <- data$Group.4 <- NULL
```

I can't figure out how to make the upc chosen be the one with the most sales. It would also be great if there were a way to do this in fewer lines of code and more elegantly.

Comment: Please include your _many lines_ of code

Comment: Would that actually be helpful to see my code? I essentially used merge() several times. But my way only randomly chooses which upc to go with rather than the one with greatest total sales.

Comment: it would help to know which functions you actually know and it might as well speed-up the answering

Comment: @HubertL OK I added in my most recent attempt. Thanks a lot.